# How to write Unit test with Mockito

Tags: java, spring, controller, mockito

I have a simple Controller that I would like to write a Mockito unit test for.  Here is the code:

```
private final UserController userCtl;

public String get(final Model model) {
    return this.userCtl.getLoginForm(model);
}
```

Here is my test:

```
@Mock
private Model model;

private DefaultControllerImpl sut;

@Before 
public void setup() { 
    this.ctl = new DefaultControllerImpl(this.userCtl, this.authService, this.orgService, this.riskSpaceService); 
    this.ctl.setMessageSource(this.messageSource); 
}

@Test
public void testGet() {        
    final String view = this.sut.get(this.model);
    assertThat(view).isEqualTo(UserController.LOGIN_PATH);
}
```

However, this test always returns null.  How can I go about writing a proper unit test for this controller?

Comment: if you are using spring-mvc and trying to test a controller, unit test with mockito may not the best solution. try spring-mvc-test. here is the link. it is integrated with spring 3.2, if you have a previous version of spring, you have to config it separately, check out this http://blog.springsource.org/2012/11/12/spring-framework-3-2-rc1-spring-mvc-test-framework/

Answer (score 1):

You don't say *what* is `null` but I'm assuming that none of your mocks are, so you must have declared the following runner on your test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

However what I can't see in your test is any behaviour added to the mocks. For example you are not telling `usrCtl` to return anything on a `getLoginForm(...)` call so it will return `null` by default - perhaps this is why you are seeing `null`.

To instruct the `usrCtl` mock to return the value you want you can do something like:

```
given(userCtl.getLoginForm(model)).willReturn(UserController.LOGIN_PATH);
```

You should take a look at the [Mockito documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html), if you haven't done so already, for further information and examples.

Answer (score 0):

You never instantiated your test class's properties.

```
private Model model = new Model(<params>)

private DefaultControllerImpl sut = new DefaultControllerImpl(<params>);
```

Comment: I should have included this code as well.  The test class is being instantiated, and the Mock objects are being injected during setup of the JUnit test.

`code`
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.ctl =
            new DefaultControllerImpl(this.userCtl,
                this.authService,
                this.orgService,
                this.riskSpaceService);

        this.ctl.setMessageSource(this.messageSource);
    }

Comment: @elpisu I hope you don't mind, but I added this code to your question  - rollback the edit if you do. :-)